# Limit Supremum and Limit Infimum of an alternating sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Alternate the terms of the sequence $ (1 + \frac {1}{n})$ and $(\frac {-1}{n})$ to obtain the sequence $(x_n)$ given by $(2,-1,3/2,-1/2, 4/3, -1/3, 5/4, -1/4, \ldots)$.

Determine the values of $\limsup(x_n)$, $\liminf(x_n)$. Also find $\sup\{x_n\}$ and $\inf\{x_n\}$.

I think that just from inspection if I were to break this into two subsequences namely $ (1 + \frac {1}{n})$ and $(\frac {-1}{n})$ I would see $(2,3/2,4/3,5/4\ldots)$ and $(-1,-1/2,-1/3, -1/4,\ldots)$, then I could see that the first is increasing and the second is decreasing.

$ (1 + \frac {1}{n}) \to 1$ as $n \to  \infty$ while  $(\frac {-1}{n}) \to 0$ as $n \to  \infty$. I suppose this would imply that $2 =\sup\{x_n\}$ and $ -1 = \inf\{x_n\}$, although I am probably wrong in that sense. So would it then follow that the limits are $\limsup(x_n) =2$ and $\liminf(x_n) = -1$? I'm very lost with the limit superior and limit inferior concept. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Intuitively, it works somewhat like this: $\limsup$ is obtained by standing at sequence point $n$, looking toward $\infty$ and taking note of the _supremum_ of all the sequence points you can see (those with index $>n$). Then you go further out, and do the same. $\limsup_{n\to \infty} x_n$ is the limit of these as you continue to walk towards $\infty$, always looking outwards and seing what the supremum of what comes _after_ is. $\liminf$ is completely analogous.

Comment: $\limsup a_n=\inf(\sup a_N)_{N\ge1}$ and $\liminf a_n=\sup(\inf a_N)_{N\ge1}$

Comment: *Informally*: We have $\{2,-1,3/2,-1/2, 4/3, -1/3, 5/4, -1/4, \ldots \}$, let try to make the sequence $( \sup a_N)_{N\ge n}$. 

So $(\sup a_n)_{n\ge1}= \sup \{2,-1,3/2, \ldots\}=2$,$\,(\sup a_n)_{n\ge2}= \sup\{-1,3/2,-1/2, 4/3, \ldots\}=3/2$, and $(\sup a_n)_{N\ge3}=\sup\{3/2,-1/2, 4/3, \ldots\}=3/2$, and so on, And you can show that $\limsup a_n=1$. Similarly for the other sequence $( \inf a_N)_{N\ge n}$.

Comment: So then is it safe to say that if I'm standing at n and looking toward infinity then since the first sequence I mentioned is decreasing then the point directly in front of me is the supremum. Then if I keep doing this it goes to 1 so the lim sup would be 1. Conversely the limit inf would be 0. My lack of understanding is in the notation then.

Comment: Alright I understand. Thank you Arthur and Jose both of those helped me visualize what was happening. I'm thinking of it as the supremum is constantly changing as the sequence moves forward and so the supremum tends towards a number. In this case one. The same for the infimum.

Comment: The more interesting visualization  I've read is the following. Suppose  we have a piston in $+\infty$ moving leftward until stopped by the presence of the sequence, where stopped is the $\sup$ of the entire sequence, but if we remove  the first member of the sequence the piston may or may not move, but for some members of the sequence the piston moves a little bit, sometimes doesn't move at all. If we keep doing this there will be a point where the piston doesn't move, this point is the $\limsup$ of the sequence. Hopefully this would help you to visualize what's going on. =)

Comment: Yes, that really does. I wish more of the concepts in real analysis could be explained in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the positive terms are decreasing and the negative terms are increasing.

Hence $\sup_{k \ge n} x_k$ will be given by the first positive term in $x_n,x_{n+1},...$, and similarly,
$\inf_{k \ge n} x_k$ will be given by the first negative term in $x_n,x_{n+1},...$.

Since the first positive term of the whole sequence is $2$, we have $\sup_n x_n = 2$, and the $\inf$ is computed similarly.

We have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \ge n} x_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \ge n} x_{2k-1} =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \ge n} (1+{1 \over k}) =
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+{1 \over n}) = 1$.

The $\liminf$ is computed in a similar fashion.

**Note**: In general, the sequence $n \mapsto \sup_{k \ge n} x_k$ is non-increasing, the $\limsup$ is the limit of this non-increasing sequence. Similarly
for $\liminf$.

Answer (score 0):

Limsup and liminf are the smallest and the bigest (maximum and minimum) values of limit points of the sequence. The given sequences has two limit points, than the biger one will be limsup and the smaller one liminf. So $limsupx_n=1$ and $liminfx_n=0$.